# Bind class to every new instance of a class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I've been taken a bunch of JavaScript riddles lately and got really stuck on this one for like a day and a half (for context, all the others took 1 hour max). Since I want to come up with the final solution myself, I will post a somewhat similar piece of code just so I can grab the general idea and implement it as per the context of the riddle.

Assume this is the piece of code:

```js
class Vehicle {
  constructor(brand, model, power) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.model = model;
    this.power = power;
  }

  info() {
    return `This vehicle is a ${this.brand} - ${this.model}, with a power of ${this.power}`;
  }
}


//do something with my class here such that
//the next calls will return/display as follows

const v = new Vehicle('Mercedes', 'C class', 12345);
console.log(v.info()); // This vehicle is a Mercedes - C class, with a power of 12345

const {
  info
} = v;
console.log(info()); // This vehicle is a Mercedes - C class, with a power of 12345



//To keep in mind, the function should stay the same, so a call to (info === v.info) should return true;
//And only the part of the code where it says to enter the code can be changed, so the class should be untouched.
```

I'm aware this shouldn't be a case where maybe it will be used in everyday life, as it is a riddle and just meant to challenge our brain, but it challenged me to the point I give up haha.

I tried looping over the entries of the Vehicle.prototype, and setting each one that is a function and is not the constructor to the same function bound to the class, or to the class.prototype or anything similar and it doesn't work.

How can I go about solving it, or at least make it so I can edit a function call for every time a new instance of that class is created?

Edit:
I tried using the bind method, even tried something like this

```
Vehicle.prototype['info'] = Vehicle.prototype['info'].bind(Vehicle.prototype);

Vehicle.prototype['info'] = Vehicle.prototype['info'].bind(Vehicle);

Vehicle.prototype['info'] = Vehicle.prototype['info'].bind(Vehicle.prototype['info']);
```

I tried many alternatives and they didn't work since I have to have it bound to each instance of the class created. So if a new instance was created, and the same was done there, each one would return data according to the instance it was extracted from.

Comment: Use the ```bind()``` method. It creates a new function that, when called, has its ```this``` keyword set to the provided value.

Comment: If you want to add code, edit in the question!

Comment: @Wimanicesir Done!

Comment: Here's an answer that appears to satisfy your requirements: https://jsfiddle.net/vscx5fra/

Comment: @Bergi: next time before waving the banhammer around, do bother reading the question.

Comment: @gog I have read the question. How is this not a duplicate? OP is asking for an overview of all the ways how to get a bound method, which the canonical topic does answer. All the approaches in the answers below can already be found there.

Comment: @Bergi: none of your links deal with the OP's very specific problem directly.

Comment: A valid solution to this puzzle should only modify two comment lines in the middle, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep `info === v.info` as `true`. You need to use `bind()`.

```js
class Vehicle {
  constructor(brand, model, power) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.model = model;
    this.power = power;
  }

  info() {
    return `This vehicle is a ${this.brand} - ${this.model}, with a power of ${this.power}`;
  }
}

const v = new Vehicle('Mercedes', 'C class', 12345);
console.log(v.info());

const info = v.info;
console.log(info.bind(v)());

console.log(info === v.info);
```

### Update:

Another elegant solution by [gog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3494774/gog). I added it here since this question is closed.

```js
class Vehicle {
    constructor(brand, model, power) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
        this.power = power;
    }

    info() {
        return `This vehicle is a ${this.brand} - ${this.model}, with a power of ${this.power}`;
    }
}


let fn = Vehicle.prototype.info
Object.defineProperty(Vehicle.prototype, 'info', {
    get() {
        return this._bound ?? (this._bound = fn.bind(this))
    }
});

const v = new Vehicle('Mercedes', 'C class', 12345);
console.log(v.info());

const {
    info
} = v;

console.log(info());

console.log(info === v.info)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `bind()` method should be used in the **constructor** of the class, not on the <strike>prototype</strike>.

If you want to bind a method to the class itself, not the instance, you can do it like this:

```
class Vehicle {
 static info() {
   return `This is a vehicle`;
 }
}

Vehicle.info = Vehicle.info.bind(Vehicle);

console.log(Vehicle.info()); // This is a vehicle
```

In this case, `Vehicle.info = Vehicle.info.bind(Vehicle);` binds the `info` method to the `Vehicle` class itself.

Comment: But in my case ```info()``` is not a static property, and the data it gets is passed by the user and not initially in the class.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is because when you destructure `info` from `v` instance, you are basically borrowing its method so `this` is no longer bound properly and you need to re-bind it.

```js
class Vehicle {
  constructor(brand, model, power) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.model = model;
    this.power = power;
  }

  info() {
    return `This vehicle is a ${this.brand} - ${this.model}, with a power of ${this.power}`;
  }
}


//do something with my class here such that
//the next calls will return/display as follows

const v = new Vehicle('Mercedes', 'C class', 12345);
console.log(v.info()); // This vehicle is a Mercedes - C class, with a power of 12345

// here is where the issue starts,
// now info is no longer "connected" to v instance,
// the function is just borrowed from that object
const {
  info
} = v;
// so you need to rebind it before use
console.log(info.bind(v)()); // This vehicle is a Mercedes - C class, with a power of 12345



//To keep in mind, the function should stay the same, so a call to (info === v.info) should return true;
//And only the part of the code where it says to enter the code can be changed, so the class should be untouched.
```